# How to target nth-child td then continuing down the list

Tags: jquery

I've targeted a specific td using the `nth-child`, but wanted to see once I've targeted that specific td that I'll be able to continue down the list after that `nth-child`, how would that be possible?

This is what I have so far:

```
var start = "3";    
var first = $("tr:first-child").find("td:nth-child("+start+")");

\\a function that allows me to go to the next td's that are after the third td (ignoring  1 & 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.nextAll()` selector to target next sibling elements:

```
var nextalltds = first.nextAll();
```

Comment: This actually worked out of everything else. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` function to select whatever element you want from a matched set of elements.

In the following example, find all rows starting from the third (index = 2) one and add `selected-row` class

```js
$('table').find('tr').filter(function(index) {
  return index > 1;
}).addClass('selected-row');
```

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse }
table td { 
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.selected-row td { background-color:#d8d8d8 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table cell</td><td>Table cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .next()?

```
var next = $("tr:first-child").find("td:nth-child("+start+")").next();
```

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:gt` selector, like this:

```js
var start = "1"; // note: works on index, so to start on the third element, use 1
var $first = $("tr:first-child td:gt(" + start + ")").addBack();
$first.addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```